# How to condition Check In\Out file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom

Is there a code by which method should I check the status of the Check Out\In?

[SPCheckOutStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.spcheckoutstatus.aspx) not correct method? Or am I not correctly calling?

`var list;
var item;
var file;
  function fileCheckIn() {
   var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
   var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
   this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("DEPLOY");
   this.item = list.getItemById(2);
   this.file = this.item.get_file();`

if (this.file.CheckOutStatus != this.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
{
    //file was checked out
     alert('Ok');
}
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `get_checkOutType()` property and `SP.CheckOutType` enum to check the status.

Modify the code as below:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("DEPLOY");
        var item = list.getItemById(2);
        var file = item.get_file();
        clientContext.load(file);                          
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
          if(file.get_checkOutType() == SP.CheckOutType.none)
                console.log(file.get_name()+ " is not checked out.");
          else if(file.get_checkOutType() == SP.CheckOutType.online)
                console.log(file.get_name()+ " is checked out for editing on server.");
          else
                console.log(file.get_name()+ " is checked out for editing on local computer.");

    },function(sender,args){
            console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace() );        
    });
}
```

Reference - [SP.CheckOutType enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408997(v=office.14).aspx)

[SP.File.checkOutType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244900.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Rest API like below to check if a file is checked out:

```
$.ajax({url: window.location.href.toLowerCase().split('pages')[0] + "_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + window.location.pathname  + "')/checkOutType",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
            success: function(data) {

                  if(data.d.CheckOutType === 0) {
                    console.log('The file is checked out');
              } else {
                    console.log('The file is not checked out');
              }

              console.log(data.d.CheckOutType, 'data.d.CheckOutType');
            }
    });
```

[Checking if a SharePoint 2013 Page is Checked Out or Published with JavaScript and REST](http://sharepointcookies.com/2015/07/checking-if-a-sharepoint-2013-page-is-checked-out-or-published-with-javascript-and-rest/)